# I want to add a link to every post in a single category on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

As title stands for what I need, I want to add a link to every post after the content in a specific category. Like  "For more details go to [https://stackoverflow.com/"](https://stackoverflow.com/%22) How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [in_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) to check for the category and put in whatever you want:

```
if ( in_category('name or slug here') ) :
  echo 'For more details go to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>';
endif;
```

You can add that after `the_content()` in your `single.php` file.

Comment: Updated the answer to add the HTML to make the link clickable.